# How to append string from a loop in C++?

Tags: c++

I am new. I am learning C++. I am trying to append specific item form a string to another string using for loop. But I am unable to do it. I found nothing helpful searching on the internet.

My code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string statement, newStatement = "";
    cin >> statement;
    for (int i = 0; i < statement.length(); i = i + 2)
    {
        newStatement.append(statement[i]);
    }
    cout << newStatement;

    return 0;
}
```

Please help me how can I do that.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`std::string::push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/push_back) to append one character to a string.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string statement, newStatement = "";
    cin >> statement;
    for (int i = 0; i < statement.length(); i = i + 2)
    {
        newStatement.push_back(statement[i]); // use push_back instead of append
    }
    cout << newStatement;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Simply doing `newStatement += statement[i];` should work too.